# Push array from function which places into another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a questions about nested functions

How can I get b array which contains [1, 2, 3] here:

```js
function someFunc() {
  const a = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3
  }]
  const b = []
  
  function someOtherFunc() {
    a.forEach(i => {
      b.push(i.id)
    })
  }
  return b
}

console.log(someFunc())
```

Comment: you aren't calling `someOtherFunc` anywhere...

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an empty array, because the `someOtherFunc` function wasn't executed.

```js
function someFunc() {
  const a = [{ id: 1}, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  let b = [];
  
  someOtherFunc();
  
  function someOtherFunc() {
    a.forEach(i => {
      b.push(i.id)
    })
  }
  return b
}

console.log(someFunc())
```

Or quicker solution, using `Array#map`.

```js
function someFunc() {
  console.log([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }].map(v => v.id));
}

someFunc();
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `return a.map(...)` would be much more efficient here.

Comment: No.. I meant completely remove `someOtherFunc()` and `b` altogether... This function can be 2 lines long